# bizzare js bug: code not being called/executed after function call, does not throw error

Tags: javascript, debugging, local-storage, next.js

I am losing my mind trying to debug this; any help at all is seriously appreciated.  After doing a great deal of process of elimination, I encountered this strange quagmire:

```
console.log('log 1') // 'log 1' printed to console
window.removeItem('item');
console.log('log 2') // nothing prints to console
```

Two questions here,

1. Why is this happening? Maybe because there is no localStorage item with that name, but then why would this halt future execution of code?
2. Why is my piece of $@#! debugger not throwing an error? (I am using Next.js with Chrome)

Comment: Did you mean to write `localStorage.removeItem('item');`?

Comment: ...shoot, well this is embarrassing.  I was so busy furiously searching through the internet that I forgot to actually look at the code in front of me.

Comment: Still, there are two questions that remain: why did the debugger not throw an error, and why would it stop the execution of future code?  Also, why are they no red squiggles under the line like there would be in Typescript or C#?

Comment: That line definitely throws an error in the browser, thus stopping execution. I'm unsure why your debugger wouldn't show it.

Comment: My intuition is that it's because the code is embedded in a Firebase promise callback.  I've had problems before where if one tries to do shady things within a Firebase callback, Firebase will completely halt.  Not even console.logs will run.  This might be true for any failing function inside the callback, not just the firebase functions.  I suppose this is good for security, but I wish I would have known about it sooner.  /:  Oh well.